# Which x86 C++ compilers are multithreaded by itself?

Tags: c++, multithreading, compiler-construction

Now almost an every user have a 2 or 4 cores on desktop (and on high number of notebooks). Power users have 6-12 cores with amd or i7.

Which x86/x86_64 C/C++ compilers can use several threads to do the compilation?

There is already a `'make -j N'`-like solutions, but sometimes (for `-fwhole-program` or `-ipo`) there is the last big and slow step, which started sequentially.

Does any of these can: GCC, Intel C++ Compiler, Borland C++ compiler, Open64, LLVM/GCC, LLVM/Clang, Sun compiler, MSVC, OpenWatcom, Pathscale, PGI, TenDRA, Digital Mars ?

Is there some higher limit of thread number for compilers, which are multithreaded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Gcc has [`-flto=n`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-flto) or `-flto=jobserver` to make the linking step (which with LTO does optimization and code generation) parallel. According to the documentation, these have been available since version 4.6, although I am not sure how good it was in those early versions.

Comment: From which version? Where is it documented? If it true that [WHOPR != LTO](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/LTO-Overview.html) and -flto may have better (or just different) result than -flto=n?

Comment: @osgx I added a link to the documentation. I don't know if there is any difference in generated code between `-flto` and `-flto=42`.

Answer (score 4):

Some build systems can compile independent modules in parallel, but the compilers themselves are still single-threaded. I'm not sure there is anything to gain by making the compiler multi-threaded. The most time-consuming compilation phase is processing all the #include dependencies and they **have** to be processed sequentially because of potential dependencies between the various headers. The other compilation phases are heavily dependent on the output of previous phases so there's little benefit to be gained from parallelism there.

Comment: The most time-consuming is the optimisation with high level (O2, O3) and the -ipo optimisation.

Comment: Code generation and global optimization takes large fraction of time too, and it *can* be done in parallel.

Comment: Couldn't you have multithreaded programs building up a thread-safe queue of include dependencies in order?
Your answer doesn't make much sense.

Comment: "The most time-consuming compilation phase is processing all the #include dependencies" - could you support this claim (e.g. by some papers or benchmarks)? In my experience many C++ codebases are dominated by template-heavy code (originating from Boost or elsewhere).

Comment: "The other compilation phases are heavily dependent on the output of previous phases" - not really e.g. GCC LTO manages to partially parallelize compilation.

Comment: Written a multithreaded compiler myself, it can easily be done. But nobody touches a compiler anymore. clang is now 20 years of age, who want to rewrite/finance this old infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

Newer Visual Studio versions can compile distinct translation units in parallel. It helps if your project uses many implementation files (such as .c, .cc, .cpp).

[MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385193%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Which version(s) of the Visual C++ compiler does this refer to?  I did not know parallel compilation within a project was supported.

Comment: its like `make -j N` solution, so it is not an answer

Comment: VS 2008 and 2010 support parallel compilation. Check the link.

Comment: Link checked. The page says "Processes" not "Threads". Also, it will do a parallel work on different files.

Comment: Yes, it only helpful if your project has many translation units. Linking and higher level optimizations are still serial.

Comment: But annoyingly it can't do nmake -j  There is a threaded nmake replacement called jom http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/jom

Answer (score 1):

It is not really possible to multi-process the link stage.  There amy be some degree of multi-threading possible but it is unlikely to give much of a performance boost.  As such many build systems will simply fire off a seperate process for seperate files.  Once they are all compiled then it will, as you note, perform a long single threaded link.  Alas, as I say, there is precious little you can do about this :(

Comment: Link stage is rather small (in terms of time) in big projects, where `-O3` or even `-ipo` or `-whole-program --combine` mode is used.

Comment: E.g. there is a file in mysql, compiling of which can long up to several hours with gcc. This is a SQL parser, a single 1 MB-sized file. Link time of it is small, but the optimisation time is huge.

Comment: IIRC the linker shipped with the Digitalmars C/C++ compiler is multi threaded (and written in ASM!) with the ends effect of being one of the fastest linkers in the world. It may not give linear speedups but it may well trim several minutes off large builds.

Comment: The Linux [`gold` linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_%28linker%29) *is* multi-threaded (and making a multi-threaded linker is less difficult than making a multi-threaded compiler...)

Comment: @osgx Not when you consider incremental builds (which is where 90% of developer time is spent). SQL is one of very few projects using [unity builds](http://mesonbuild.com/Unity-builds.html) so I wouldn't consider it a good example.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Note that author of Gold reported [no speedups from multithreading the linker](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/34417.pdf). I'd love to know if there are more up-to-date benchmarks...

Comment: Efficient multithreaded linker: https://github.com/rui314/mold

Answer (score 1):

Multithreaded compilation is not really useful as build systems (Make, Ninja) will start multiple compilation units at once.
And as Ferrucio stated, concurrent compilation is really difficult to implement.

Multithreaded linking can though be useful (concurrent .o/.a reading and symbol resolution.) as this will most likely be the last build step.

Gnu Gold linker can be multithreaded, with the LLVM ThinLTO implementation:
https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThinLTO.html

Comment: "Multithreaded compilation is not really useful" - it may be very useful if your compilation time is dominated by a single C++ file (which I've experienced multiple times both with OSS and commercial projects) or when you do incremental build after changing a a single file. Parallel compilation has been in LLVM devmeetings so people do consider it.

Comment: "Gnu Gold linker can be multithreaded" - note that [Gold paper](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/34417.pdf) claims that there was no speedup for multithreaded linking.

Comment: @yugr The major speedup improvement comes from ThinLTO as I stated. But (i missread some months ago) this speedup is only over not-thin LTO.

Answer (score 1):

[Go 1.9](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9) compiler claims to have:

> Parallel Compilation
>
> The Go compiler now supports compiling a package's functions in parallel, taking advantage of multiple cores. This is in addition to the go command's existing support for parallel compilation of separate packages.

but of course, it compiles Go, not C++

I can't name any C++ compiler doing likewise, even in October 2017. But I guess that the multi-threaded Go compiler shows that multi-threaded C or C++ compilers are (in principle) possible. But they are few of them, and making new ones is a [huge work](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/273711/40065), and you'll practically need to start such an effort from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual C++, I am not aware whether it does any parallel compilation (I don't think so).  For versions later than Visual Studio 2005 (i.e. Visual C++ 8), the projects within a solution are built in parallel as far as is allowed by the solution dependency graph.

Comment: As you say, individual projects within a solution are compiled in parallel.  A single project is compiled on a single core, single-threadedly.  The link step is single threaded.