# Compiler which can run its components in parallel mode

Tags: compiler-construction

Do we have today a compiler infrastructure, which can run its components in parallel mode to increase compilation speed in common? For example when code generator starts emit the code for target platform, *possibly*, compiler infrastructure can do lexical & syntactical analysis for next source file at the same time. Does we have any related research in this topic?

UPD0: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4430154/1778275) is a relative answer.

Comment: If you have multiple cores, you can simply compile multiple source files simultaneously. Few projects are made from a single source file and those that are won't benefit much from a multi-threaded compiler. But most projects would benefit from multiple concurrent compilations. And yes, this is already supported in some platforms.

Comment: @Pete, I agree, that we can compile multiple source files simultaneously if we have machine with multiple cores. But let's go deep. I am asking about parallel running of internal compiler  components to save a time.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. What I was saying is that I don't think there's any benefit in that. Certainly not enough of one to justify the added complexity. There's no real added complexity to compiling multiple source files simultaneously and it will provide more of a benefit than a multi-threaded compiler would.

Comment: Actually, you can save a lot of time running shared infrastructure; how many time do you want to process that same include file?  If you insist on compiles-as-separate processes, then you have to reprocess each include file in each process because there is no cross-process sharing of work done.   If there's a shared parallel core, any piece of work like this can in principal be cached to avoid doing it twice.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LLVM doesn't perform multithreaded compilation, but it theoretically could because each compiler pass can only mutate a certain 'scope' of the IR.  From [the docs](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html):

> Depending on how your pass works, you should inherit from the ModulePass , CallGraphSCCPass, FunctionPass , or LoopPass, or RegionPass, or BasicBlockPass classes, which gives the system more information about what your pass does, and how it can be combined with other passes. One of the main features of the LLVM Pass Framework is that it schedules passes to run in an efficient way based on the constraints that your pass meets (which are indicated by which class they derive from).

In practice, fine-grained parallelism in compiler passes probably isn't worth the overhead of synchronization (and the inevitable bugs when a pass touches more than it claims to) given that individual source files in large programs can be compiled in parallel.  The different pass classes are primarily useful for documentation.  They can also help in scheduling passes in a cache-friendly way; for example, when running a bunch of FunctionPasses on all the translation unit's functions, it's faster to run each pass on one function (keeping it in cache) before moving to the next function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I fully agree that we should care about final overhead when we are trying to generate new ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit does exactly this.

DMS is infrastructure for building arbitrary, custom program analysis and transformation tools. It has built-in machinery to support fully context-free parsing, symbol table/control flow/data flow graph construction, as well as source-level pattern matching and source-to-source transformations.   Given a programming language description (combination of BNF, attribute grammars, language-specific fact collection to support symbol tables, control/data flow facts, etc.), DMS parses the source text to ASTs, and runs the various fact collectors (usually implemented as attribute grammars) to build classic compiler data structures.  It does this for a C, C++14, Java 1.8, and a variety of other languages.

Because DMS's main use case is for whole program analysis and transformation, performance is important.  So DMS is implemented in a parallel programming, PARLANSE, which makes fine grain irregular-size task parallelism available and efficient(~~ 50 machine instructions overhead for what amounts to fork and join, total)  [Big chunks of program that you can parallelize are pretty hard to find].  Whether one *uses* this parallelism in a DMS application is up to the tool engineer, but it is made easy to use in a number of places.  Baseline, all the data structures support by DMS are parallel-safe; many of its internal algorithms are implemented in parallel where practical.   The attribute grammars associated with a language front end are largely functional; they are compiled to PARLANSE partial-order parallel constructs.   The irregular parallelism exposed is executed by a work-stealing scheduler; the programmer does not allocate or schedule threads, ever. [All this runs on stock Windows].

Some places where DMS has used parallelism:

- Streaming lexer.   The lexer can (and in some applications is) decoupled from parsing by generating a stream.   A lexer can generate lexemes independently of what the parser (or other lexical analysis tool) is doing.  The steam is managed as a producer/consumer queue in a relatively obvious way.
- Symbol table construction: maps of identifier uses to types.  This mostly amounts to a tree crawl root downward on pass to form scopes as futures, and leaf upward on a second pass to collect identifiers, determine the scope in which they are identified and/or insert identifier declarations in scopes.  This parallelizes pretty nicely.   At whole-program level, one often discovers that symbols used in one module are entirely defined in others (Java is particularly good example);  one now needs on-demand launch of parsing and name resolution to provide such referenced data.  For our Java front end, this is accomplished by a fast internal fork; the forking computation sets up a "future" for the desired result and waits, freeing the processor to go do other work.   The full Java front end, given several thousand Java files to process, simultaneously is running parallel parses, attribute grammars for symbol table construction and dynamic partial order constructs for dependencies across compilation units.   This keeps an 8 or 16 core CPU pretty busy for a bit.   (We do have full C and C++ parsers; we have not yet applied these ideas to preprocessing but its on our list of to-dos).
- Parallel application of code transformations.   Given a set of transforms or simplifications to do, they can be applied to separate compilation units easily in parallel, and to separate subtrees within a compilation unit.  (Some might say you could apply the transformations in entirely separate proceess, and that would be true, but those seperate processes would then each individually have to do the name and type resolution I described above).
- Sorting.  There's a variety of places in DMS where big lists need to sorted.   We run these as recursive, parallel merge-sorts.
- Specific applications.  Our CloneDR, based on DMS, which finds duplicated code across large source code bases, does the clone detection in parallel.

What we have not done is classic compilations (source code to object code).  There isn't any reason we could not do this parallel, but DMS's principal application isn't compiling.  We see lots of compilers out there, and don't see a lot of point in replicating what they do.